# MYSQL and phpmyadmin not allowing me to create user table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

im trying to create a table using mysql and phpmyadmin with the w

```
CREATE DATABASE android_api 

USE 'android_api'
CREATE TABLE users(
id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
unique_id VARCHAR(23) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
encrypted_password VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
salt VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
created_at DATETIME,
updated_at DATETIME NULL
);
```

but i keep recieving an error :

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'USE 'android_api'
>       CREATE TABLE users(
>       id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMEN' at line 3

i was wondering if anybody could help me

NOTE - i have tried putting '' around the database name and id, unique_id and so on.

Comment: Probably a missing semi colon before `USE`

Comment: Try using ticks around the table name instead of quotes.  There is a difference in 'users' and `users`.  You'll find ticks at the top left of your key board, same key as ~.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE DATABASE android_api;

USE android_api;

CREATE TABLE users(
    id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    unique_id VARCHAR(23) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    encrypted_password VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    salt VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    created_at DATETIME,
    updated_at DATETIME NULL
);
```

Separate three statements with `;`

Comment: The missing semi-colons was the problem I saw too.  @Joe solution should do the trick.

Comment: @DDeMartini: Yes. I've written to puth semicolon at the end of every statement

Comment: Remove quotes around your 'USE' statement when switching to the database..   mysqli doesn't like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE DATABASE android_api;

USE android_api;

CREATE TABLE users(
    id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    unique_id VARCHAR(23) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    encrypted_password VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    salt VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    created_at DATETIME,
    updated_at DATETIME NULL
```

);

It should work like this:

```
mysql-sql> use android_api;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
mysql-sql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| android_api        |
| devel              |
[...]
+--------------------+
```

Can verify you created the table

```
mysql-sql> show tables;
+-----------------------+  
| Tables_in_android_api |
+-----------------------+
| users                 |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```